# ArcSDE - Creating new install on new database with existing SDE schema

Tags: oracle-spatial

I asked a question before, but was probably not specific enough, so didn't get the information I required. My fault completely.

I am creating a new sde instance on a server.  This needs to be pointed at an existing Oracle 11g database, that has a pre exisiting SDE schema and data in it.

Now all the installs I have seen, have created all of the system tables, but this one doesn't need to, as they are there. Also, which is more alarming, is that I cannot perform an upgrade, as it hasn't been installed before.

Not too sure how to take it from here.  I don't normally work with SDE, buit have thoroughly researched the issue.  Has anyone seen this issue, or have advice as regards the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This is my plan of action.

- Dump file of Oracle non spatial data
- Install SDE
- Create new Schema
- export SDE data from old DB (sdeexport)
- import SDE data from sdeexport file

We'll see how that fares, but it appears the only way to me.

Comment: I think you will find this works - are you using ArcSDE 10?

Comment: No, 9.3.1 unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to clearly understand your pre-conditions:

1. You have existing Oracle 11g instance.
2. There is an SDE schema there with data.
3. There is no ArcSDE installation and service.

Am I right?

If yes, then actually I think you can access you data right now via Direct Connection.
You have no need in ArcSDE service for accessing you data.

To setup ArcSDE service you need to perform following actions:

1. install ArcSDE. Skipping Post-Install step if you are using Windows.
2. create ArcSDE service using `sdeservice` command.

You can have more info from this Esri article:
[HowTo: Manually install ArcSDE for Oracle on Windows](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23821)

You need to perform steps 7, 10 and 11.

Refer to [ArcSDE Administration Command Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/admincmdref.htm) for further info.

Comment: No, we have to create the new 11g instance, and migrate the data from 9i, and also create a new instance of SDE.  I have got to the stage now in my career that I can now install SDE blindfolded!

Comment: In any case I think you can consider transfering sde schema by dump (or tablespace) as an option.

Comment: Not too sure about this, as the indexing gets fubar'd.  I'll have a look, but the last time we did this, it was a rm -r jobby